# how to avoid server names in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, dns, server, alias

The time has come to migrate to a new web server.  We've always referenced the server directly by its name.  I'm told that (outside of connection strings) it's not always practical to reference the server by a DNS name.

So now when moving web sites to a new server with a new name, I'm faced with finding all instances of the old server name in settings, connection strings and (God forbid) hard coded programs and updating it with the new server name.

Well, if I'm going to do that, can't I replace it with some sort of alias or some other means of indirection so that I don't have to do this again next time?  What's the best practice here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can connect by IP address.  You can store the IP address in an appname.ini file.  Whenever you need it you get it from the file.  When you have to change servers, just edit the ini file once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood. You should always reference the server by a DNS name, not a *host* name. For example, instead of `web-server-yoda.mysite.com` (the name of the server) you should create a DNS entry for `intranet.mysite.com` and point that at the server. Then, if you need to change servers, it's a simple matter of updating the DNS entry to point to the new server.

As for how to set up DNS, that's not really anything to do with programming. You should look at our site site, [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I don't think that would work in a file path, would it?

Comment: @BWK1954 What are you talking about "file path"? You mean a UNC path? Like `\\servername\foldername\file.txt`? Yes, DNS is built into the entire network stack.

Comment: What mason is referring to is called a CNAME, and this definitely a preferred method to referring directly to a server name.

Comment: The old server is running Windows Server 2003.  If I attempt to access a file on it by using a DNS alias (see this article; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record which distinguishes the alias from the CNAME), then I get this error: "

Comment: (the error is) "You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network..."  This article, http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000991.htm explains the problem nicely and presents a solution.  However, I'd rather not modify the registry of and reboot a production server.  It may even require an update.  But I could try it on the new server.

Comment: @BWK1954 Your issue is not about programming. I suggest you take it up with [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).